# Need awk or sed help

Tags: shell

`{'REST_SPS': u'4.1.4.339', 'REST_ROM': u'U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020)', 'REST_SMART': u'2.65', 'Server': 'example', 'REST_ILO': u'2.18 Jun 22 2020', 'REST_1G': u'20.14.62', 'REST_DISK': u'HPD5', 'REST_10G_2': u'14.26.1040', 'REST_IB': u'12.24.1000', 'REST_IE': u'0.2.2.0', 'REST_10G_1': u'14.26.1040'}`

The above is a line from here I want output as below

```
4.1.4.339, U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020), 2.65, example, 2.18 Jun 22 2020, 20.14.62, HPD5,14.26.1040,  12.24.1000, 0.2.2.0, 14.26.1040
```

Comment: That looks like a python dict object - if that is the case, have you considered using python to manipulate it (perhaps with the CSV DictWriter)?

Answer (score 1):

As steeldriver suggests:

```bsh
line="{'REST_SPS': u'4.1.4.339', 'REST_ROM': u'U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020)', 'REST_SMART': u'2.65', 'Server': 'example', 'REST_ILO': u'2.18 Jun 22 2020', 'REST_1G': u'20.14.62', 'REST_DISK': u'HPD5', 'REST_10G_2': u'14.26.1040', 'REST_IB': u'12.24.1000', 'REST_IE': u'0.2.2.0', 'REST_10G_1': u'14.26.1040'}"

echo "$line" | python3 -c '
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
d = eval(line)
keys = ["REST_SPS", "REST_ROM", "REST_SMART", "Server", "REST_ILO", "REST_1G", "REST_DISK", "REST_10G_2", "REST_IB", "REST_IE", "REST_10G_1"]
print(", ".join([d[k] for k in keys]))
'
```

```
4.1.4.339, U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020), 2.65, example, 2.18 Jun 22 2020, 20.14.62, HPD5, 14.26.1040, 12.24.1000, 0.2.2.0, 14.26.1040
```

I'm not really a python guy, so this could probably use some improvement.

And if you're reading lines from a file, you don't want to invoke python once for each line: do the processing in python.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/.*:/,"",$i);print $i}}' filename|sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| sed "s/[u'}]//g"| awk 'ORS="," {print $0}'|sed "s/,$//g"
```

output

```
4.1.4.339,U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020),2.65,example,2.18 Jn 22 2020,20.14.62,HPD5,14.26.1040,12.24.1000,0.2.2.0,14.26.1040
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it completely in `sed` but, as you can see `sed` is not the ideal tool for this particular use case unless you like to write very long `sed`commands. I strongly recommend you use `awk` instead.

```
$ sed -e 's/[{}]//g; s/, /,/g; s/: /\n/g' file | \ 
sed -e "s/^u//g; s/'//g; s/,/\n/g" | sed -n 'g;n;p' | \
sed -n 's/.*/&,/;H;$x;$s/,\n/, /g;$s/\n\(.*\)/\1/;$s/\(.*\),/\1/;$p'
4.1.4.339, U32 v2.34 (04/08/2020), 2.65, example, 2.18 Jun 22 2020, 20.14.62, HPD5, 14.26.1040, 12.24.1000, 0.2.2.0, 14.26.1040
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @SanjoyPaul.  Please upvote the good answers to your question.